# Three.js Tweening issue: start value always remains the same

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap, tween

I have a problem for tweening my camera.position . I create a codepen with the minimum of code just to reproduce my issue and I annotate all my code. I also put a lot of console.log() for debugging purpose .

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cid-wings-the-encoder/pen/PoNjVvL?editors=0011)

the start point is my camera.postion

```
camera.position.z = 30;
```

and my tween001

```
    var tween001 = gsap.to(camera.position,{ delay:2,duration:5,z:60,onUpdate:function(){
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    console.log("play");
  },onComplete:function(){console.log("complete");},ease:"elastic"});
```

so the tween is about to move my camera from the Z = 30 to Z = 60

its work perfectly but ... When the user move the camera when the user move/over/click on the 3d its fire and eventlistener that pause "tween001.pause()"   I want the tween001 use the "actual" camera.postion and not when the camera.postion used when the tween 001 get fire .

Cause when the tween001 is played again or it resume from a pause the start point used is the default one x=0 y=0 z=30 .

An idle function  play the tween001 again

```
window.setInterval(checkTime, 1000);// every 1 second launch checktime()

  function checkTime() { //idleCounter get 1 every second and at 5 second coz timeout is 5 checktime relaunch the tween001
    if (idlecounter < timeout) {
      idlecounter++;

      //console.log("++ ");
    } else if (idlecounter == timeout) {
      tween001.play();
      console.log('timeout');
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry for my english (I'm french by the way ^^)

Comment: Easiest solution I can see is to create a new tween every time you want to fire it instead of creating a tween at the start and playing it.

Comment: Same question on the GreenSock forums: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/25358-threejs-and-gsap-tween-update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to understand that GSAP assumes it's the only thing that's controlling `camera.position`. So when you declare `gsap.to(camera.position, {z: 60})` it'll store internally the starting position (30) and the ending (60) to build its timeline. It doesn't know that you've changed the z-position with the mousewheel, so when you call `.play()` it'll still assume you want to go from 30 to 60.

What you have to do is re-initialize a new tween each time so it has to look up the starting position when you want to replay it:

```js
var tween001;
function doTween() {
    tween001 = gsap.to(camera.position, { delay:2,duration:5, z:60, ease:"elastic", onComplete:function(){
      // camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      console.log("complete");
    }});
}
```

- Notice that I declared `var tween001` outside the function, in the global scope, so you can still call `tween001.pause()` whenever you need
- There's no need to update the projection matrix while changing position.

Now, when you're ready to start the animation again, instead of using `tween001.play()` you can call `doTween()` and it'll build a new timeline that re-reads the camera's current z-position to start the animation:

```js
// ...
else if (idlecounter == timeout) {
    doTween();
    idlecounter = 0;
}
```

[see here for the updated codepen](https://codepen.io/marquizzo/pen/vYGJgNz?)